# Make classes from data attribute containing multiple items

Tags: jquery, arrays

Kind of a hard one to title, sorry.

I have a data attr called colors. e.g.   `<div class="square" data-colors="opt1, opt2, opt4">`

I want to get this attribute and split it into 3 different classes.  So I'm left with something like `.opt1 .opt2 .opt3`

I accidentally got to this point:

```
var colors = $('.square.active').data('colors'),
    splitColors = colors.split(',');

      console.log(splitColors);
```

Which returns an array of my colors:

```
["opt1", " opt2", " opt4"]
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to do things, I feel like I might be making more work for myself.  Is there a simpler way of doing this?  Or should I continue this way?  If so, how would I get each item in the array and turn it into a usable class?

I have an example here, you can see the results in the console:
https://jsfiddle.net/7z972udn/

Click a Square, press the button, that returns you with the array with the colors assigned to that square.

On click of the button, I'd like to remove the hidden class from the items in the array.  I would assume the end result would be something like this: `$('.opt1, .opt2, .opt3').removeClass('hidden');`

I'm just not sure how to get to that point from where I'm at.

Comment: Why don't you add the period to the class names inside the data. Then you could use join() js function in order to get one string with '.opt1, .opt2, .opt3'

Comment: You mentioned you would like to remove 'hidden ' class from the array but you array only has opt1, opt2, opt3. Also, you used 'option' tag selector in your code but you don't have any element in your DOM. Could you explain what are your exactly looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to keep your way

You could add the periods(.) as prefix

```
<div class="square" data-colors=".opt1, .opt2, .opt4">
```

Then split the way you're doing

```
var colors = $('.square.active').data('colors');
splitColors = colors.split(',');
```

Then turn the split colors array into a single string using [join()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) function

```
splitColorString = splitColors.join();
```

this will generate the string

```
 '.opt1, .opt2, .opt3'
```

Then do the jquery remove class thing

```
$(splitColorString).removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: removeClass only works on jquery html objects. Applying that to a string won't do anything.

Comment: The string is working as a selector, is not working as pure string.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Your selector is not a valid html selector. You need to use $('div').removeClass('hidden') if you are trying to remove the class.

Comment: If the string gets a pattern like .class1, .class2, .class3 then it is a valid html selector.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_multiple_classes.asp

Comment: @ggderas can you show how? that doesn't seem to work, but maybe i'm missing something: https://jsfiddle.net/792ofjhs/

Comment: My bad, it works, but because the divs don't "regain" the _hidden_ class when I clicked the button, I wasn't seeing it happen correctly. +1

Comment: Much better!!  Thank you :)